# Updating column collation from utf8_general_ci to utf8_bin breaks an index

Tags: mysql, mariadb, indices

I've noticed that after updating a column collation from *utf8_general_ci* to *utf8_bin* the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_table
WHERE updated_column = 'some_value'
```

returns empty result set (which should be non-empty). *updated_column* has a non-unique index.

Why is it happening and how to rebuild the index to match the update?

**P.S.** MySql installation:

```
mysql.exe  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.7-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 9a78a283f4ee7e8ccc4afb1d8a24c662fa4c634b
```

Comment: Please provide specific strings, so we can better address your question.  If the data is sensitive, make up a test case that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_bin` is a binary collation and compares strings only on their unicode code point values.

`utf8_general_ci` will match also characters that are canonically equivalent but have a different code point value. Additionally comparisons are made case insensitive (ci).

If you updated_column contains the value 'Some_value' a search for 'some_value' using utf8_general_ci will match, while using utf8_bin will not match.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case. The table is queried by the exactly matching value and after rebuilding the index (drop/create) it works fine.